# Is $L=\{w\mid \text{ same number of 010 and 101}\}$ regular?

Tags: computability, regular-language

I tried to prove that this language is regular using NFA or regular expressions and didn't succeed.

I would like to see some solutions

Comment: Why do you think it is regular? Also, what do you mean by "same number"? How are you counting? Does $010111010$ count?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the clever edit, I learned of $\mid$. thank you

Comment: I am not sure its regular. and I count every instance even if there is an intersections

Answer (score 4):

This is not a regular language. The "problem" is you need to count how many $010$ and how many $101$ strings appear in a word and regular languages don't know how to do this.

For a more formal proof start by defining a homomorphism $0 \mapsto 00100$ and $1 \mapsto 11011$. If your language was regular, then the inverse image of the homomorphism is also regular, but this inverse image is just 
$$\{ w \mid 0,1\; \mbox{appears the same number of times}\}.$$
Intersecting it with the language $\{0^n 1^m\}$ (which is also regular) you get another regular language which is $\{0^n 1^n\}$ - contradiction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Thanks, corrected it.

Comment: Can you explain why is {w∣0,1 appears the same number of times}. is the inverse of the homomorphism?

Comment: @Eyalbason : If w is any word and $\varphi(w)$ is its image, then the only way 010 can appear in the image is inside $\varphi(0)=00100$ and similarly 101 appears only in $\varphi(1)=11011$